# Can I mark beginning and end of streaks of data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets which I have combined. One of the datasets is continuous and complete through time, and the other dataset is based on events in time.

| year-quarter | continuous data | event data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014Q1 | 0.29 | nan |
| 2014Q2 | 0.31 | nan |
| 2014Q3 | 0.32 | 1 |
| 2014Q4 | 0.29 | 3 |
| 2015Q1 | 0.11 | nan |
| 2015Q2 | 0.23 | nan |
| 2015Q3 | 0.24 | nan |
| 2015Q4 | 0.25 | 2 |
| 2016Q1 | 0.26 | 1 |
| 2016Q2 | 0.21 | 1 |
| 2016Q3 | 0.12 | 1 |
| 2016Q4 | 0.20 | nan |
| 2017Q1 | 0.21 | nan |
| 2017Q2 | 0.25 | 3 |

I would like to append this pandas dataframe with two columns marking the beginning and the end of an event. See below for example:

| year-quarter | continuous data | event data | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014Q1 | 0.29 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2014Q2 | 0.31 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2014Q3 | 0.32 | 1 | 1 | nan |
| 2014Q4 | 0.29 | 3 | nan | 1 |
| 2015Q1 | 0.11 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2015Q2 | 0.23 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2015Q3 | 0.24 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2015Q4 | 0.25 | 2 | 1 | nan |
| 2016Q1 | 0.26 | 1 | nan | nan |
| 2016Q2 | 0.21 | 1 | nan | nan |
| 2016Q3 | 0.12 | 1 | nan | 1 |
| 2016Q4 | 0.20 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2017Q1 | 0.21 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2017Q2 | 0.25 | 3 | 1 | 1 |

Do any of you know of a way to create this?

I've tried searching around this forum, but have been unable to find guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html)/[`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) :

```
events = (df["event data"].notna() & df["event data"].shift().isna()).cumsum()

g = df.groupby(events)["event data"] #this returns a `SeriesGroupBy` object

df.loc[g.apply(lambda s: s.first_valid_index()).dropna().tolist(), "start"] = 1
df.loc[g.apply(lambda s: s.last_valid_index()).dropna().tolist(), "end"] = 1
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   year-quarter  continuous data  event data  start  end
0        2014Q1             0.29         NaN    NaN  NaN
1        2014Q2             0.31         NaN    NaN  NaN
2        2014Q3             0.32        1.00   1.00  NaN
3        2014Q4             0.29        3.00    NaN 1.00
4        2015Q1             0.11         NaN    NaN  NaN
5        2015Q2             0.23         NaN    NaN  NaN
6        2015Q3             0.24         NaN    NaN  NaN
7        2015Q4             0.25        2.00   1.00  NaN
8        2016Q1             0.26        1.00    NaN  NaN
9        2016Q2             0.21        1.00    NaN  NaN
10       2016Q3             0.12        1.00    NaN 1.00
11       2016Q4             0.20         NaN    NaN  NaN
12       2017Q1             0.21         NaN    NaN  NaN
13       2017Q2             0.25        3.00   1.00 1.00
```

Comment: Loved the use of `first_valid_index` +1

Answer (score 1):

Let's do

```
# Define groups of non-null start and non-null end of `event data` values
groups = df['event data'].notnull().diff().eq(1).cumsum()

# Assign `1` to the start and end of each group
df.loc[groups.groupby(groups).agg(lambda s: s.index[0]).values, 'start'] = 1
df.loc[groups.groupby(groups).agg(lambda s: s.index[-1]).values, 'end'] = 1

# Overwrite the `1`s above with `nan`s for groups that are all `nan`s
all_nans = df.groupby(groups)['event data'].transform(lambda s: s.isna().all())
df.start, df.end = df.start.mask(all_nans), df.end.mask(all_nans)

# Note: the overwriting step is unnecessary if you use 
# `.first_valid_index` and `.last_valid_index` instead of 
# `s.index[0]` and `s.index[-1]` above, as suggested by 
# @Timeless in their answer.
```

---

```
   year-quarter  continuous data  event data  start  end
0        2014Q1             0.29         NaN    NaN  NaN
1        2014Q2             0.31         NaN    NaN  NaN
2        2014Q3             0.32         1.0    1.0  NaN
3        2014Q4             0.29         3.0    NaN  1.0
4        2015Q1             0.11         NaN    NaN  NaN
5        2015Q2             0.23         NaN    NaN  NaN
6        2015Q3             0.24         NaN    NaN  NaN
7        2015Q4             0.25         2.0    1.0  NaN
8        2016Q1             0.26         1.0    NaN  NaN
9        2016Q2             0.21         1.0    NaN  NaN
10       2016Q3             0.12         1.0    NaN  1.0
11       2016Q4             0.20         NaN    NaN  NaN
12       2017Q1             0.21         NaN    NaN  NaN
13       2017Q2             0.25         3.0    1.0  1.0
```